# Array to string conversion problem in my php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add this line of code in my

```
=> array('name'=>'amount', 'type'=>'date', 'ord'=>'desc')
```

but i'm having problems keep saying

> Array to string conversion

i don't know what do to ?

Here is my code where i put the code

```
if ($showdims)
    $col = array(_("Period"), _("Amount"), _("Dim. incl."), _("Last Year"));
else
    $col = array(_("Period"), _("Amount") => array('fun'=>'trans_view'),_("Last Year"));

table_header($col);
```

it would see this when and give hyperlink for my database

```
function trans_view($trans)
{
    return get_budget_trans_view_str(SA_BUDGETENTRY, $trans["amount"]);
}
function get_budget_trans_view_str($type, $trans_no, $label="", 
    $icon=false, $class='', $id='')
    {
        $viewer = "gl/view/";
        if ($type == SA_BUDGETENTRY)
        $viewer .= "budget_view.php";

        else
        return null;

    if ($label == "")
        $label = $trans_no;

    return viewer_link($label, $viewer, $class, $id,  $icon);

    }
```

Comment: What does `_` function do? And I suppose `table_header` outputs headers for a table, where each header is a string. So what do you expect to happen with `_("Amount") => array('name'=>'amount', 'type'=>'date', 'ord'=>'desc')`?

Comment: also what does `table_header` do? Maybe you are trying to bind an array to a string value in a SQL request? Or else, why did you tag mysql to your question?

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] unfortunately. We can't answer this without the code for the `_()` function

Comment: it would give me hyperlink for my database _("Amount") => array('name'=>'amount', 'type'=>'date', 'ord'=>'desc')

Comment: Thanks for the help i just redo my code from scratch

Comment: You are using `get_budget_trans_view_str` second parameter `$trans_no` as a label for your link apparently (if third argument `$label` is not specified). If it's an array, this can't work. You have to do a special case, for example with `is_array`. We can't guess what label you want to use for this case

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

```
<?php
       $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
       echo $string_version = implode('', $arr);
 ?>
```